# When exactly does Github check for merge conflicts on pull request?

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

This may sound like a very simple question.

I raised a PR on Github 3 days back and there were no merge conflicts at the time of PR creation. Today, I open the PR link and there are still no merge conflicts. PR reviewer says that I should rebase locally first and then push the code, then Github will check for merge conflicts. My point is that the Github(website) checks for merge conflicts on every other PR merge i.e. when the `master` branch code is updated, so there is no need for me to rebase locally and then push the code.

Am I right and is it safe for reviewer to approve the PR without me rebasing the code locally as it does not show any merge conflicts on **Github.com**.

I would appreciate if someone can also post a official documentation where Github devs have defined the process.

Comment: Yes, there is no *need* to rebase if github does not show any merge conflicts. In a pull request, the current HEADs of the branches you want to merge are compared, so if no conflict is shown, the merge can be performed in the current state of both branches. Having that said, if the projects common workflow is to rebase before merging, you should stick to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PR reviewer says that I should rebase locally first and then push the
>   code

Pull request reviewer is wrong. Let's see my a pull request what has 2 commits ( https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/pull/5102 )

Thinking in simple and reality way: conflicts, it means you cannot keep 2 different contents from 2 developer in the same line of code. **Code snippet from developer Bob and code snippet from developer John cannot stand in the same line.** Resolving conflict, it means choose either Bob's code or either John's code.

For understanding about merge conficts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#understand-merge-conflicts

Comment: Thanks for confirming and giving an example.